# Printing the highest of two values WITHOUT using if statements

Tags: c

I'm doing a homework assignment in C and I've run into a little trouble. 
After calculating two values, I have to be able to print the highest of two values *without* using logical operators, relational operators, or selection constructs.  I've already used calculations that determine the larger of the two values, but I don't know if that is very useful going forward.

I would also like to clarify that I am not printing the maximum value, rather I am supposed to print the maximum option.  For example, is option 1 = 2000 and option 2 = 3000, I want to be able to print out "option 2 is the larger one".

I should also say that following with the rest of the assignment this selection is typically only done with mathematical operations `+*-%/` and `pow()`

Comment: And I guess the ternary conditional expression `?:` is not allowed either?

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem with your solution?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You claim that you've found a way, so what are you actually asking? Additionally, please upload some code so that we can help further

Comment: @Frontear It's "have to be able". Was confused too...

Comment: Sounds like XY-problem, you know. Probably the part of "*calculating two values*" should imply the right order.

Comment: i found a way to print the maximum VALUE, not the maximum option as the second paragraph suggests.  As for ?: I would assume not.

Comment: Post the code you have tried.  A [mcve].

Comment: @Gox How is reversing the digits in a number like coding `max(a,b)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's more like a mathematical problem:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  int o1 = 4;
  int o2 = 2;

  //res > 0 if, and only if, o2 > o1
  int res = o2 - o1;

  // module of res
  double module = pow(pow(res, 2), 0.5);

  //res2 = 1 if res > 0
  //res2 = -1 if res < 0
  int res2 = res/(int)module;

  printf("option%d is greater.\n", (3+res2)/2);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Warning 1: It doesn't work when o1==o2

Warning 2: This answer treat this problem as a mathematical problem.
The system in C don't guarantee to hold the value of a double as an exact number, but it holds as an approximation.
So, as chux pointed out, it may not give the right answer for large numbers.

You may have `double a = x/|x|` giving `a` a value of `0.9999` in C, making `int b = (int)a` having a value of `0`

Comment: `module` may slightly differ from `|res|` with large `res` as the square `pow(res, 2)` is not the exact mathematical square with large `res`.  In that case and with weak `pow`, the `(int)module` may be off by one, messing up hoped for division.  `o2 - o1` is subject to overflow.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely should not be used in a program, but as I imagine its a question on a list, and me being a computer science professor, I think that is the answer that is expected.

Comment: vinicius de novaes, What do you get when `o1 == o2`?  I get divide by 0 - an exception fault.

Comment: Chux, I would get that too, but as the question did not set a rule for the case that o1==o2 I had not bother with that.

Comment: I'm trying to think in a way to fix that btw

Comment: As a mathematician, offering coding that uses a mathematical model is understandable.  As a computer science professional, assuming that is less so.  It is exactly the real limitations  of coding that deserve our attention to detail.  Sometimes these little issues like [unexpected overflow](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/ariane.html) are expensive.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Your caution on the use of a `double` has shortcomings. There's nothing inaccurate about a `double`. Merely they are a subset of the real numbers that's distributed linearly in exponential space, cf. `int` which is a subset of the real numbers that's distributed linearly.

Comment: @Bathsheba The `double` caution is not about the `double` encoding as you well described.  It is the `double` math of `pow(pow(res, 2), 0.5)` to achieve `fabs(res)` that is the problem.  Code here can incur a result that differs from `fabs(res)` leading to an incorrect result.

Comment: @chux: Yes, that's a good point indeed. Using `res/round(module)` would, I think, fix it.

Comment: @Bathsheba `round()` will help except when the ULP is 0.5 (near the error level), then it is a coin flip.

Comment: @chux I’m going to have to think about that one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the function [fmax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmax). It takes doubles as arguments, so you may have to cast your numbers into doubles.

Answer (score 1):

> highest of two values
>   only done with mathematical operations (+*-%/ and pow)

When the values are both > 0, find the 2 quotients a/b, b/a.  One of the quotients will be 0 (assuming types are some integer) and the other 1 or more.  (Or both quotients are 1 when values are the same).

Perform

```
pow(one_or_more, 0);  // 1 (v2 > v1)
pow(0, one_or_more);  // 0 (v1 > v2) 
pow(1,1);             // 1 (same)
```

Use 0,1 to index the answer.

Sample

```
int a[2] = { value1, value2 };
int index = pow(a[1]/a[0], a[0]/a[1]);
printf("%d\n", a[index]);
// or "to print the maximum option"
printf("%d\n", index);
```

---

The allowable use `pow()` hints to this approach.

Side benefit:  No overflow when values are > 0. `-,+,*` tend to open the door to overflow possibility and that is avoided.

Down side: Trouble with values <= 0.

Answer (score 0):

The greater of two `int` types `x`, and `y` is

```
x - ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)))
```

`x` is `z` if `x ^ z` is `0`, and similarly for `y`.

Comment: Now how do you use this to produce the desired result?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Honestly, the youth of today need to be spoonfed ;-)

Comment: (x < y) isn't it a " logical operators, relational operators"?

Comment: @Hedgehog: This better?

Comment: yeah, we aren’t able to use any comparison operators (=<> etc.) as well as & |

Comment: @Bobthebuilder: You can recast & in terms of ^ and some others but you know what, I'm too old for that. Are you sure you can't use `&`? I'd understand the rationale for not using `&&`.

Comment: Well it's not spoonfeeding so much as literally just answering the question that was asked 

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use sign bit as an index for array.

```
signed char index1 = (option1value - option2value) >> 7;
signed char index2 = (option2value - option1value) >> 7;
```

If `option1value > option2value` then leading bit in `index1` will be 0 and after shifts it will be 0.

If `option1value < option2value` then leading bit in `index1` will be 1 and after shifts it will be 1.

You put your "verbal text" into array using the indexes. Then always print from 0 index.

You need to select right data type for your values and adjust shift bits too.

Comment: `option1value - option2value` is subject to `int` overflow.  Signed `int` overflow is  _undefined behavior_ (UB).

Comment: @chux, do you mean "unsigned int"? Or in case two values are both MIN_INT? Then the author need to take long int.

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463659/printing-the-highest-of-two-values-without-using-if-statements/54463910?noredirect=1#comment95736178_54463910).  This solution will not work for all `int`, yet OP has not specified type nor range.

Comment: I just provided the idea, The author need to pick right data types and etc.

Answer (score -1):

Without arrays as I understand they are not allowed. Only math

```
void printlarger(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d\n", a * (int)pow(a/b, b/a) + b * (int)pow(b/a, a/b));
}


int main()
{
    printlarger(3,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printlarger(42,1)` attempts `c[1 - 42])`.